# What is the advantages of using Dozer in Spring Hibernate project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dozer

I simply want to know what is the benefit of using Dozer in project. Here I am really confuse How to use ? and Why I use ? Please help me. I want to map my entity classes to Dto classes and want data flow on my gui through dto classes. And when I saved any data from Gui to DB then I want to convert my Dto Class to Dao Class.

Comment: Try to elaborate more your question. Using Dozer for what?

Comment: voted to close the question. opinion based

Comment: I edited my question . If you like then vote me in positive not negative Because I don't know the purpose of Dozer and Why is it used ? So I ask a general question for knowledge . So please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Dozer` is about mapping **a Java Bean to another Java Bean** for some field based value propagation and it is all about in memory objects.
- While `Hibernate` is about mapping **POJO (Domain objects) to a relational database**.

So as you can see, they are not apparentely related one to the other, and any need to use both of them should be upon a **personal** choice.

As your question has been edited:

- *A basic conceptual architecture* should be to map your *Entities* (Domain Objects - *you did call it dao classes*) through `Hibernate` to a database.
- Then those *Entities* can be mapped to some *Java Beans* (which you did call dto classes) using `Dozer`.

Comment: thanks tmarwen . If you like my question you can vote me up.

Comment: Done but you should work more on perfecting your questions, be more relevant from the first shot next time ;)